# Novice Java Student: How can I create a series of output dialog boxes using JOptionpane?

Tags: java, dialog, joptionpane

From 1925 through 1963, Burma Shave advertising signs appeared next to high- ways all across the United States. There were always four or five signs in a row containing pieces of a rhyme, followed by a final sign that read “Burma Shave.” For example, one set of signs that has been preserved by the Smithsonian Institution reads as follows:

Shaving brushes 
You'll soon see 'em 
On a shelf
In some museum 
Burma Shave

Find a classic Burma Shave rhyme on the Web. Write, compile, and test a class that produces a series of four dialog boxes so that each displays one line of a Burma Shave slogan in turn. Save the class as BurmaShave.java.

Comment: Take a look at [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: seems like homework task...what have you tried so far ?

Comment: What the? Did you just copy and paste your homework assignment?

Comment: yes, I did. I'm looking through the book, but cannot find anything regarding consecutive windows. I'm reading the How to Make Dialogs page now. Thank you for your help

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for all of your help and negative feedback, it helped me realize that asking questions is always a bad thing... way to go, guys.

Comment: import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class BurmaShave

{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A Beard That's Rough");
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "And Overgrown");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Is Better Than");
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A Chaperone");
   }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to start by looking at the documentation for [`JOptionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html), specifically [`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object%29).

Sample usage from the javadoc:

> ```
> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "alert", "alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
> ```

Just write your main method do do this several (ie: four, according to your question) times in a row, replacing the strings "alert" with whatever messages you want.